# Email notifications with attachment when uploading files to s3

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I'm attempting to create email notifications with attachments when using Sprout Forms and S3 assets.

Given `Sprout Forms 2.1.5` & `Craft Pro 2.5.2760`

And a form with an Asset field

And default upload location in an S3 bucket
[image: Default upload location in an S3 bucket]

And enable notifications set to true
[image: Enable notifications set to true]

And enable file attachments set to true

When a user submits a form, no email is sent and the following error is logged in `sproutforms.log`

`Craft\S3AssetSourceType and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getBasePath".`

Looking into the docs, `S3AssetSourceType` does NOT have a method named `getBasePath`, but `localAssetSourceType` does.

My question is, does sproutforms support notification emails with attachments when using S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Sprout Forms does not support email attachments when using S3 assets.

Answer (score 1):

[Sprout Forms](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms) v2.3.0 added support for S3 Asset uploads and file attachments.

--

OUTDATED: As of this post, Sprout Forms does not yet support email attachments using S3.

As a workaround, it is possible to override the `email.html` notification template using [Template Overrides](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/customization/template-overrides) and link to or display S3 assets in the way you would provide a link to any asset:

```
{{ asset.getUrl() }}
```